# How to change img src recursively from Chrome Js console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

on a page fully loaded how can i change (recursively) img src (or even basic text) from chrome js console?
I need to see the effects in real time!
So definitely need to change the given srcA into srcB :D

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by changing the source "recursively"?

Comment: All I can say to this question is: "what?" What is it you need to do? Why? In response to what? And "recursively," what do you think that word means? Because I don't think it means what you think it means...

Comment: Err for "recursively" i mean for all correspondence on the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (tested on SO):

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); for(var i in a) if(a[i].src != undefined && a[i].src.indexOf("static") != -1) a[i].src=".";
```

Replace the dot with a new required URL, "static" is a placeholder of an old URL fragment.

Comment: Thank you very much is exactly what I wanted, I apologize for the inconvenience about the terms!
Thank you again!